# What is going on in this code ? I do not understand how this works could someone please step me through this

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, currying

Can someone please explained the steps that are happening in this code particularly the marked part. Is it recursive how does it slot together..?

```js
const func = x => k => func (k (x))
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^      
const add = x => y =>
  x + y

func(1)(add(2))(add(2))(console.log);
```

Comment: Looks more like a coding curiosity, or minified/mangled code. Anyway it's very hard to understand, nobody would ever write this kind of things

Comment: @JeremyThille it's a fairly standard functional code. Hardly something nobody would write or even much out of the ordinary.

Comment: Well anyway I don't think I'd ever write something that twisted

Comment: This is recursive function application you cannot escape from. The basic application pattern is `func(1) (inc) (log);` logs 2, `func(1) (inc) (inc) (log)` logs 3, etc. The underlying structure that is build looks like `inc(inc(...(1)))`.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, `func` doesn't type check because we can't construct the infinite type `t a ~ (a -> b) -> t b`. However, we can get around that restriction by creating a new data type as follows.

```js
// Chain :: (forall b. (a -> b) -> Chain b) -> Chain a
const Chain = chain => ({ chain });

// func :: a -> Chain a
const func = x => Chain(k => func(k(x)));

// add :: Number -> Number -> Number
const add = x => y => x + y;

// trace :: a -> a
const trace = x => {
    console.log(x);
    return x;
};

// Chain Number
func(1).chain(add(2)).chain(add(2)).chain(trace);
```

Now, `Chain` is a very weird data type. It's an infinite chain of type-aligned functions.

```hs
   Chain a
 = (a -> b) -> Chain b
 = (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> Chain c
 = (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> Chain d
 -- ad infinitum
```

However, this data type is not very useful for purely functional programming because you can never consume a `Chain` value. The only way you can make use of intermediate results in the chain is by using an impure function like `trace`. I'd suggest that you avoid such useless data types altogether.